# Why can't I translate my plane downwards?

Tags: math, opengl, linear-algebra

I suspect I'm screwing up my math, but I can't seem to figure out where I've went wrong.

Here's my scene:

[image]

The green wooden plane is defined as a set of vertices:

```
    private Vertex[] planeVertices = new[]
        {
            /*0*/new Vertex(-1, 0, 1,  0,0,   0, 1, 0),
            /*1*/new Vertex( 1, 0, 1,  1,0,   0, 1, 0),
            /*2*/new Vertex( 1, 0,-1,  1,1,   0, 1, 0),
            /*3*/new Vertex(-1, 0,-1,  0,1,   0, 1, 0),
        };
```

The first 3 numbers of the Vertex are the coords, the latter ones you can ignore. Then I'm rendering it like this:

```
        planeVao.Bind();
        textureSampler.Value = 1;
        modelMatrix.Value = new Matrix4(
            5, 0, 0, 0,
            0, 1, 0, -3,
            0, 0, 5, 0,
            0, 0, 0, 1);
        GL.DrawElements(BeginMode.Triangles, planeIndices.Length,
            DrawElementsType.UnsignedInt, IntPtr.Zero);
```

And in the Vertex shader I've got:

```
gl_Position = ProjectionMatrix * ViewMatrix * ModelMatrix * vec4(Position, 1.0);
```

The `modelMatrix.Value` assignment is supposed to stretch the plane by a factor of 5 along the X and Z axis (which it does, otherwise it would be the same size as the cube) and then the -3 is supposed to move it down 3 units, but it has no effect. That's the part I can't figure out.

In the GLSL `ModelMatrix` has the value of `modelMatrix.Value`...

So if we take the first vertex for example (-1,0,0) and we multiply it by that matrix.... for the `y` coordinate we have [0,1,0,-3]<sup>T</sup> * [-1,0,0,1] = (0*-1 + 1*0 + 0*0 + 1*-3) = -3, no? It appears as though it's coming out zero though.

---

Changing the ModelMatrix to this (replaced the top-right value, T<sub>x</sub>, with 1):

```
        modelMatrix.Value = new Matrix4(
            5, 0, 0, 1,
            0, 1, 0, -3,
            0, 0, 5, 0,
            0, 0, 0, 1);
```

Has this effect:

[image]

Which doesn't look like a translation at all... not sure what's going on here.

---

Okay, I checked that my math wasn't wrong:

*snip* [picture was slightly wrong]

That's the result I would have expected... now I'm wondering if my mistake is elsewhere.

---

Okay the view matrix is:

```
{(0.8192319, -0.2529707, 0.5146502, 0)
(0, 0.8974438, 0.4411287, 0)
(-0.5734624, -0.3613867, 0.7352146, 0)
(8.940697E-08, -2.235174E-07, -6.800735, 1)}
```

And the projection matrix is:

```
{(1.299038, 0, 0, 0)
(0, 1.732051, 0, 0)
(0, 0, -1.020202, -1)
(0, 0, -2.020202, 0)}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're switching the last row with the last column. The view matrix has the translation vector along the bottom row, but you're creating your model's translation along the last column, which deals with skewing / some other perpsective stuff I haven't studied much.

Just switch the location of the translation and it'll work. If your transformations are all uniform, you can also just take the transpose of the matrix to get the same result.

Comment: Oh, weird..the OpenGL Book (http://openglbook.com/the-book/chapter-4-entering-the-third-dimension/#toc-translation-matrix) said that last column was for translations, and that made sense to me when I did the math. Or you're saying it's because of how I have my view matrix set up? I guess that makes sense. glUniform has a nice option to automatically transpose it, maybe I'll use that :)

Comment: yeah, that works too, but IIRC OpenTK is row-major order. `Matrix4.CreateTranslation` will provide a proper translation matrix that you can multiply with your other matrix to get the model matrix.

Comment: There's a `Matrix4.CreateTranslation`?? I was specifically looking for that, but I didn't see it. I found all the rotation ones, but not the translation one. Will have to look again when I get home. Smart guy figured out I was using OpenTK :D

Comment: `GL.DrawElements` was enough for me to know that it was OpenTK. Also in the nightly builds I think the rotation and scaling methods were changed to `CreateRotation` and `CreateScale`.

Comment: Are the nightlies pretty stable? Maybe I'll switch over to that. It's just a fun little personal learning project anyway.

Comment: I think they're pretty stable, I'm not too sure though as I haven't had the chance to extensively test them.

Answer (score 4):

You are on the right track, but your matrix is transposed from how it should be. That's why you're getting a crazy skewing when you tried different values. [See this.](http://www.opengl.org/resources/faq/technical/transformations.htm)

Put the translation vector in the last row, not the last column and you'll be good.

```
modelMatrix.Value = new Matrix4(
        5, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 1, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 5, 0,
        0, 0, -3, 1);
```

Comment: Ah.. 9.005 says its along the bottom row too. Cool, will check that link out more later. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, if you read the link, you'll see that OpenGL is trying to be agnostic to a row-major/col-major setup, it's all in how you decide to multiply your vector with the matrix. So if you had pre-multiplied your vector with your matrix, you would have gotten your correct result. But since you post-multiply, the matrix needs to have the translation vector in the last row. This got me, since in school we typically pre-multiplied in our notation, but in practice, most code uses post-multiplication style.

Comment: My linear algebra is all rusty, but the way I've been thinking about is that you work from right to left. You start with the position vector then apply all your transformations to it right to left. I didn't even think you could do it the other way around!